# How to get user to input phone number based on dictionary I created and get them to either enter key or value in format XXX-XXX-XXXX?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, formatting, key

Okay, so first off, let me share my code and then I will ask my
question. This is the code I have so far:

```
restaurant_dictionary = {2: ['a','A','b','B','c','C'],
                         3: ['d','D','e','E','f','F'],
                         4: ['g','G','h','H','i','I'],
                         5: ['j','J','k','K','l','L'],
                         6: ['m','M','n','N','o','O'],
                         7: ['p','P','q','Q','r','R','s','S'],
                         8: ['t','T','u','U','v','V'],
                         9: ['w','W','x','X','y','Y','z','Z']}

while key,value not in restaurant_dictionary:
    restaurant_number = raw_input("Please enter a phone number to translate:")
```

Now, my question is, I want a user to input a phone number in the
format XXX-XXX-XXXX, and I want to first print, on the screen for the
user to see, `"Please enter a phone number to translate:"`. Then, I want
to let them input 10 letters or digits for the phone number, based on
the `restaurant_dictionary` I created above. I want to print the final
phone number they input with dashes in between the first three and
second three letters/digits and in between the second three and last
four letters/digits.

Then, based on my restaurant dictionary above, it
should be an easy matter of translating their input into only the
digits that I use as keys for my values above. I started a `while` loop
above, as you can see, because I figured that if they don't give valid
input that corresponds to my dictionary, I should give them the
opportunity to reenter the letter/digit.

Oh, and here is a sample of how the program should function when it is
complete:

```
Enter a phone number to be translated:555-GET-FOOD↵

    555-438-3663↵

Enter a phone number to be translated:abc-flo-wers↵

    222-356-9377↵
```

Comment: You need to create a reverse dictionary that maps letters to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve the issue:

```py
restaurant_dictionary = {('a', 'b', 'c'):      2,
                         ('d', 'e', 'f'):      3,
                         ('g', 'h', 'i'):      4,
                         ('j', 'k', 'l'):      5,
                         ('m', 'n', 'o'):      6,
                         ('p', 'q', 'r', 's'): 7,
                         ('t', 'u', 'v'):      8,
                         ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'): 9}

phone_nr = list(input('Please enter Your phone number: ').lower().replace('-', ''))

temp_lst = list()
for char in phone_nr:
    if char.isdigit():
        temp_lst.append(char)
        continue
    for key, item in restaurant_dictionary.items():
        if char in key:
            temp_lst.append(str(item))
            break

phone_nr = ''.join(temp_lst)
print(f'{phone_nr[:3]}-{phone_nr[3:6]}-{phone_nr[6:11]}')
```

to mention, at least in this case there was no need to include both capital and lowercase letters in the dictionary since the user input can be lowered altogether and then You could eval the whole thing against lowercase letters. it saves some space and time

Comment: Mr./Ms. Matiiss, This Answer was great and nailed the problem PERFECTLY!! Thank you so much!!! Okay, well, now I have a heck of a lot of memorization to do, but thank you, this was great! In German, das wahr ein Meisterstück! That was a masterpiece!

Comment: @ZAB it's Mr. (but You don't have to use that) but anyways IMO You don't really need to memorize say specific syntax because that can always be looked up in the docs or search google, the basic syntax and some built-in stuff as well as other libraries You will learn with time depending on how much You use that stuff, it would be more important to memorize/learn concepts or be able to at least logically think of how to solve an issue, basically have an idea of how to do sth, then solve it and it is fine if You search stuff up since it would be hard to memorise everything. good luck with coding!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a reverse dictionary, which you could hardcode or create on-the-fly from a version the dictionary you have in your question with the uppercase letters removed (since there's no need to have both).

Here's a demo:

```
restaurant_dictionary = {2: ['a','b','c'],
                         3: ['d','e','f'],
                         4: ['g','h','i'],
                         5: ['j','k','l'],
                         6: ['m','n','o'],
                         7: ['p','q','r','s'],
                         8: ['t','u','v'],
                         9: ['w','x','y','z']}

# Construct a reverse mapping (i.e. letters to number)
letters = [letter for letters in restaurant_dictionary.values() for letter in letters]
rev_dict = {}
for letter in letters:
    for d, chars in restaurant_dictionary.items():
        if letter in chars:
            rev_dict[letter] = str(d)
            break

def convert(phone_num):
    return ''.join(rev_dict.get(char, char) for char in phone_num.lower())

#phone_num = list(input('Please enter your phone number: ')

for phone_num in ('555-GET-FOOD', 'abc-flo-wers', 'PYT-HON-TEST'):
    print(f'{phone_num} -> {convert(phone_num)}')
```

Output:

```
555-GET-FOOD -> 555-438-3663
abc-flo-wers -> 222-356-9377
PYT-HON-TEST -> 798-466-8378
```

Comment: Mr. Martineau, this was a great answer! I liked your answer just as much as I liked Matiiss's above! They were both perfect answers! Now, I have to get to work on memorizing this code, but thank you very much! I wish to memorize your code because, when I eventually become a programmer, it would be great if I could do stuff like this by heart!

Comment: ZAB: You're welcome. @Matiiss' answer is a good one IMO, and is probably more realistic for a dictionary of this size (that probably won't ever change). I posted my answer mostly just to show an alternative way of doing things and illustrate how to write "[data-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming)" code (code whose execution is driven by data supplied to it as opposed to hardcoding the steps it does) — that's what I think you should memorize.